# built-in for generating array of plots?

Tags: d3.js

I need to arrange several plots in a (possibly "incomplete") rectangular array.  (By "incomplete" I mean that the last row of the array may have fewer cells than does the first row.)

I implemented an approach for doing this that relies on HTML tables, as shown in this [silly example](http://bl.ocks.org/kynnjo/7027894), but it seems to me that this is the kind of thing that should be done entirely within d3.js.  Before re-inventing the wheel, is there a built-in way to do this?  (I'm hoping to find a way that incorporates refinements, such as axes and tickmarks, and takes care of corner cases, including "incomplete" arrays, as defined above.)

Comment: There's more going on in your example than I can afford to get into at the moment, but here's a guiding principle: In the same way that you're using selections with data binding to create N `path`s for each chart, you'd also use data binding to create the charts' containers –– rather than creating them using a `while` loop. It helps to construct the plotted data as a 2 dimensional array, with charts in tier 1 and paths in tier 2. You'd create all the charts by binding to the outer array, and then, using a `each`, bind the data for each chart's paths to its container's children. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the same selections API you used to build the chart itself.  So instead of something like `d3.select('body').append('svg')`, you can do this:

```
 var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll(".pie")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg")
      .attr("class", "pie")
      .attr("width", radius * 2)
      .attr("height", radius * 2)
```

Demo using multiple donut charts:  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3888852